# WebMvcTest not ignoring custom redis configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, redis

The main class is like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@ComponentScan({"com.sample", "com.sample.lib"})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    /**
     * The main method.
     *
     * @param args the arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    /**
     * Configure.
     *
     * @param builder the builder
     * @return the spring application builder
     */
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

The custom config

```
@Configuration
public class RedissonSpringDataConfig {

    @Bean
    public RedissonConnectionFactory redissonConnectionFactory(RedissonClient redisson) {
        return new RedissonConnectionFactory(redisson);
    }
   .....
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ConfigController.class ,excludeAutoConfiguration = { RedissonConfiguration.class,
        RedisAutoConfiguration.class, RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class, RedissonSpringDataConfig.class })
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
//@TestPropertySource(properties="spring.data.redis.repositories.enabled=false")
class ConfigControllerTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

This throws

`org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.redisson.api.RedissonClient]: Factory method 'redisson' threw exception; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: failed to resolve 'redis' after 4 queries`

I tried a bunch of options with TestPropertySource annotation. I read a couple of answers that ComponentScan would be the source of this error but couldn't fix with a couple of what I thought would be workarounds. Can someone help to ignore the custom redis client config class?

I commented out the @Configuration on custom configuration class but this would not be a graceful workaround.

Comment: Because yoyu put an `@ComponentScan` (and `@EnableCaching`) on your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class. This disables the possibility for the test to disable certain parts as those are hardcoded backing in due to those annotations and scanning. Remove those and put them on an `@Configuration` class instead. Also your `@SpringBootApplication` class should be in `com.sample` and then you don't need the `@ComponentScan` and your test will just work.

Answer (score 0):

M. Deinum has given the correct answer. Sine you want use slice test, you need to simplify you @SpringBootApplication class, move the custom directive to a separate class

Please refer to: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.user-configuration-and-slicing